# Plotting trajectories over an unit sphere surface

Tags: plotting

I have a data set which describes the magnetization direction of a material. It is normalized so I would like to plot it as a unit vector which moves over the surface according with the data file.

The file structure is:

```
t[s]         mx             my             mz
...          ...            ...            ...
...          ...            ...            ...
```

I managed to plot points over the sphere, but I cannot create the unit vector neither use `Animate[]` to create the animation.

[image]

Comment: Once you have a point ${\bf p}$ on your sphere, your vector is $\alpha {\bf p}$ for some $\alpha >0$.  Use `Arrow[{{px, py, pz},1.1 {px, py, pz}}]`

Comment: If you need a unit vector, just use `Normalize`